# Where does the question & answers stored when, we use 'Ask a Question' in community

Tags: community, knowledge, community-builder, articles, community-cloud

As I am using 'Customer Service' community template & where I want this community to be accessed publicly.

Also I want to post the question using '**Ask A Question**' publicly. But when I use this community using a authenticated user then ask a question work perfectly But, for guest user it ask for login when I click on 'Ask A Question' button.

Is there any standard way to achieve this?

If Not then, I want to achieve this by custom way using custom component. So first, I want to know where this question & it's answer stores.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ask a question" is a standard component and requires community users to log in.

The standard docs indicate that one needs to login in order to use this .

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_ask_community.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

You can create a custom component if you need this functionality to work for guest users (unauthenticated users). A chatter feed item(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) record is created with type of question post.

Comment: Hello @Mohith, Thanks for your reply. As I have just used the 'ask a question' for a authenticated user, But when I am trying to find that question in back end in sfdc But, I can't. Can You help me on this?

Comment: Yes you should be able to run a soql on Feed Item object with networkID as community Id and type as "Question Post"

Comment: Thanks @mohith.. that worked.

Comment: Hi @mohith, have quickly just checked by querying on feedtem object & got the asked questions records there. But for the guest user we can't create feedItem record. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000keDRAAY

Comment: One other alternative would be put into a custom object and then a future or a queueable job can move that record to feeditem as an anonymous user

Comment: You might pick a community user just for this.